# Using a subquery to calculate a difference

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use a subquery to calculate the difference between two calculations. I have a 'country' table which has 'population' and 'gnp' as fields. Attempting to write a query that will find all the countries that have a PerCapita GNP (ie. GNP/Population) greater than that of the USA. There also needs to be a column that includes the Difference between these countries' PerCapita GNP and that of the USA. My problem is somewhere in the difference subquery.

So far:-

```
SELECT name as Country, gnp/population*1000 as PerCapita,
(SELECT (c1.gnp/population*1000)-(c2.gnp/population*1000)
FROM country c2
WHERE c2.name = 'United States')
FROM country c1
WHERE gnp/population*1000 > (SELECT gnp/population*1000
FROM country
WHERE country.name = 'United States')
AND population >0;
```

The problem is the difference returned is a massive negative number. Obviously there is a problem in the subquery to get the difference but I can't see it.

The issue was placing c1.gnp/population*1000 inside my subquery. By moving it outside the calculation works.

```
SELECT name as Country, gnp/population*1000 as PerCapita, c1.gnp/population*1000 - 
(SELECT c2.gnp/population*1000 
FROM country c2 
WHERE c2.name = 'United States') 
FROM country c1 
WHERE gnp/population*1000 > (SELECT gnp/population*1000 <br>
FROM country 
WHERE country.name = 'United States') 
AND population >0;
```

Comment: Population: C1 or C2? How does it work without being qualified?

Comment: Adding c1.population does nothing for the difference query (or anything actually). That is only there to make sure there is no divide by 0 error.

Comment: No, I mean how does the use of "population" work inside the sub-query, when it is not qualified?

Comment: @StephLocke, you have just made the query harder to read!

Comment: @I.K. I beg to differ as the logic is centralised into a single statement, but it's also not the way I would necessarily write it in real life - I'd use a scalar variable to store the value so that the calc is only done the once as this would prevent the query time from exploding after the table grows

Comment: @StephLocke, I can't see how you think that the query is now easier to read. Logic aside, that query is now harder to read. We had a developer who did similar type of code formatting (or lack of I should really say) at our company - eventually he got fired as other developers were sick to death of trying to make his queries easier to read.

Comment: @I.K. the aim of this site is to provide constructive answers. If you dispute my formatting, suggest an edit to my answer and/or provide detailed criticism.  Currently the high-level statement and assertion that my formatting is a fireable offence gives myself, the OP, and future visitors no insight into where the formatting should be different.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pre-calculating the USA value, and using this value for doing the comparisons.

As a rule, the more times you try to do a nested subquery, the worse your performance will be as well making your code dramatically more complex.  You can normally rewrite these into JOINs instead which can help reduce some of the need to repeatedly do a calculation.

You haven't said what RDBMS you are using so there might be more effective ways of getting the comparison value into your query (for instance by declaring and assigning it as a scalar variable value) so this is the most ANSI-compliant way of doing it:

```
SELECT name as Country, 
gnp/population*1000 as PerCapita,
gnp/population*1000 - c2.percapita as Difference

FROM country c1 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT gnp/population*1000  as percapita
             FROM country 
             WHERE country.name = 'United States' ) c2 
WHERE gnp/population*1000 > c2.percapita
AND population >0
```

Comment: Apologies, using Oracle.

Comment: Also I should have mentioned that this is a subquery lesson, so we are supposed to use those instead of a join. Thank you though.

Comment: @user3261297 - If this is homework, you should add the "homework" tag and let people know this in your question.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, will do.